# What is the meaning of $g(dx)$ or $dg(x)$ in an integral

Tags: integration

How can I interpret/solve an integration like:

$$
\int f(x) \mathbf{d}g(x)
$$

or

$$
\int f(x) g(\mathbf{d}x)
$$

Comment: $\mathrm{d}g(x) = \tfrac{\mathrm{d}g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: You may want to google "Riemann-Stieltjes Integral"

Comment: @K.Stm. That is only true under certain conditions on $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the type of integration you are doing, the first integral is a *[Riemann-Stieltjes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Stieltjes_integral)* or a *[Lebesgue-Stieltjes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration)* integral.

I'll assume you're looking at integration in the Riemann sense (hence, a Riemann-Stieltjes integral).

Under certain conditions (namely, that $g(x)$ is differentiable), you can write
$$\int f(x) dg(x) = \int f(x)g'(x)dx.$$

This may not always be the case. In fact, the integral exists even when $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ have countably many discontinuities -- as long as those discontinuities are not in the same place!

One way of looking at the Riemann-Stieltjes integral is thus:

For a normal Riemann integral, you are computing the area under a curve along some interval in the $x$ axis. This $x$-axis could represent, say, position.

In a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, you are integrating over an interval that is being transformed by some monotonic function $g$. So imagine that you are integrating over a distance being warped by a theoretical warp drive.

More generally, this integral is useful when you need to integrate over some set that has a lot of "weirdness" -- this arises in probability theory, for instance.

---

Regarding your second integral, and with some enlightenment from the book you linked, this is an example of a [*Lebesgue Integral*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration). Lebesgue integration is similar to Riemann integration, but, loosely speaking, it uses the concept of "measure" as the thing that we integrate over.

In this case, the author constructs a measure based on an indicator function (essentially, this creates a measure equal to the number of times something happens). Then, the notation in your second integral indicates we're computing a Lebesgue integral over this measure.

Incidentally, if you're unfamiliar with Lebesgue integration, the statement on Page 3 of your book might be more enlightening if you read it right to left.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I found the second integral on page 3 of this book: http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/43/87/68/PDF/FnT1.pdf where it is written $\int f(x) \phi(dx)$. Actually, $\phi(A)$ shows the number of points inside the area $A$. Could you have a look at the book and update your answer about the second part of my question.

Comment: @Mohsen Done...